# Can't get Extended User Access Token from Facebook with OAuth2 NodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I'd try to get Extended User Access Token from OAuth2 with Nodejs
Actually, the program send out a message (on Browser) with:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3…2Fcallback&scope=user_about_me%2Cpublish_actions&client_id=487932668044758. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Using standard express generator, I modified a code in a index.js as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var OAuth2 = require('oauth').OAuth2;
var router = express.Router();

var oauth2 = new OAuth2("487932668044758",
    "0793918b3ab637b2096787e10643980a",
    "", "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth",
    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token",
    null);


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        // title: 'Express'
    });
});

router.post('/userToken', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body) {
        return
        res.sendStatus(400)
    }
    var uid = req.body.uid;
    var token = req.body.token;
    validate_uid_token(uid, token, res);
    console.log('req:', req.body);
    console.log("uid: ", uid);
    console.log('token: ', token);

    // res.send("okie");
});

router.get("/callback", function(req, res) {
    console.log('here..form callback');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    if (req.error_reason) {
        res.send(req.error_reason);
    }
    if (req.query.code) {
        var loginCode = req.query.code;
        var redirect_uri = "/"; // Path_To_Be_Redirected_to_After_Verification
        // For eg. "/facebook/callback"
        oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(loginCode, {
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                redirect_uri: redirect_uri
            },
            function(err, accessToken, refreshToken, params) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    res.send(err);
                    return;
                }
                var access_token = accessToken;
                console.log('access_token : ', access_token);
                // var expires = params.expires;
                // console.log('expires : ', expires);
                req.session.access_token = access_token;
                // req.session.expires = expires;
            }
        );
    }
    // res.send('okie');
});

function validate_uid_token(uid, token, res) {

    var redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000" + "/callback";
    // For eg. "http://localhost:3000/facebook/callback"
    var params = {
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'scope': 'user_about_me,publish_actions'
    };

    res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizeUrl(params));
}

module.exports = router;
```

Click on a url in error message. Browser throws out ma JSON message as

```
{"statusCode":400,"data":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":191}}"}
```

Could someone help me please...Thank to much..

Comment: you have mentioned two different redirect uri in your code..but there should be one redirect uri

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use Passport.js together with the `passport-facebook` strategy. This hides away most of the complexity involved.

See

- http://passportjs.org/
- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

Comment: Thank @Tobi...but I have to avoid passportjs becase system has use JWT already. They are using no cookies technique..:(..

Comment: Sorry, but where is your current code using JWT? And FB is not sending JWT either as far as I know

Comment: I am going to add JWT later for my web app.. These steps of my app are:
User login to app. I am get app-user-token of face via javascript and ship them to server..And I extend app-user-token to long-live-token follow these steps in this site
https://medium.com/@TheBigFatNoob/working-on-facebooks-graph-api-using-node-js-4bd107ad8c61